# duplicate value for resource 'attr/rippleColor' with config ''

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

after adding dependency in gradle 
" implementation 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.+@aar"
the gradle build fails with a message

> C:/Users/RABIA QAYYUM/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar/c0fad67b1d4195f9d3a0471ff37ff15f/res/values/values.xml
>   error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/rippleColor' with config ''.
>   error: resource previously defined here.
>   null
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

and

> error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/rippleColor' with config ''.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/rippleColor' with config ''., sources=[C:\Users\RABIA QAYYUM.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\c0fad67b1d4195f9d3a0471ff37ff15f\res\values\values.xml:203:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Comment: can someone solve this issue.

Comment: do you have ant attrs.xml file in values folder of resource?